# Parent key not found with @MapsId

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java8, SpringBoot 2.3.7 and JPA with Oracle

There is this legacy table (I cannot touch it, as it is in production with other applications)

```
TRANSFE (TRA_ID_PK NUMBER, ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER, .... )
CONSTRAINT "TRANSFE_UNIQUE" UNIQUE ("TRA_ID_PK")
```

In my new application some of the new Transfe will be TransfeIn, with only one field, so I created this table

```
TRANSFE_IN (ID NUMBER, ....)
CONSTRAINT "TRANSF_IN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
```

Everything works fine with Jpa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSFE")
public class Transfe implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TRA_ID_PK")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_TRANSFES")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_SW_TRANSFERENCIAS", sequenceName="SEQ_TRANSFES", allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRA_ID")
    private Account account;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TransfeIn transfeIn;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSFE_IN")
public class TransferenciaEntrant {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "transfeIn")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Transfe transfe;
```

The problem raises when I add this to TRANSFE_IN

```
CONSTRAINT "TRANSFE_IN_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID") REFERENCES "TRANSFE" ("TRA_ID_PK")
```

So when there is a new TransfeIn to be stored with

```
accountRepository.save(account)
```

(Account has a @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) List transfes), I get

```
SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TRANSFE_ENTR_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

In the logs, I can see how a new TRANSFE_IN row with the right ID (taken from SEQ_TRANSFES) is being inserted. But the table TRANSFE is empty, yet.

What am I doing wrong? Should I not use the FK? Or there is something in the annotations to be changed?

Comment: `when there is a new TransfeIn to be stored` - please show how you do it.

Comment: `@MapsId` seems to be an alternative to `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` not an option ... https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/59301703.html,  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Example_of_cascaded_primary_keys_and_mixed_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_mapping_annotations_using_PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Comment: Seems odd that you try to save `Transfe` through `Account`. I guess the collection of `Transfe` in `Account` will become quite big? IMO you should save `Transfe` instances directly instead. Not sure about the ordering issue that you face, but you could disable cascading for `Transfe#transfeIn` and in a custom `save` implementation save the `TransfeIn` after persisting the `Transfe` entity.